# Handling boolean function in an if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean

I have inhereted some code and I see somthing curious in there:

```
if (true == someFuncThatReturnsBool())
{
   // Do somthing
}

bool someFuncThatReturnsBool()
{
    bool retVal = false;
    // .... do some stuff

    return retVal;
}
```

In the "if" statement they have used `true == someFuncThatReturnsBool()` as a boolean expression, where for boolean values I would normally do:

```
if (someFuncThatReturnsBool())
{
   // Do somthing
}
```

What, if any, is the difference to the generated code?
Is there any advantage to using the "true ==" notation, other then perhaps for some clarity that the function returns a boolean?... type checking??, personally I can't see any advantage...

Thanks :)

Comment: You are correct. There is no advantage, just wasted and redundant syntax, and possibly pointless extra bytecode as well. Somebody didn't understand the language. Why stop at ('true == ...)`? Why not `(true == (true == ...))`?

Comment: @EJP lol, thanks!... this is what I thought, but when I see someone has done somthing I "don't get" I figure its worth asking about it ... like, what did they know that I don't! :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour ah, if so I do appologies, I did look but I did not think to actually add the code in the title! - so I missed that one

Comment: @code_fodder: No need to apologise; it's not something that's easy to search for. Duplicates aren't (usually) deleted, and can make searching easier in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What, if any, is the difference to the generated code?

none.

> Is there any advantage to using the "true ==" notation, other then
>   perhaps for some clarity that the function returns a boolean?

IFF the function is named poorly then maybe I would write the explicit version. Otherwise, if it is apparent from the function that it is a boolean check (i.e. `is_XXX` fashion), then there is no reason to use it.

Comment: If the function is named poorly, I'd change its name.  Using some twisted notation like `if ( true == function() )` is not going to make things more readable.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I would change the name also, but then that is not always possible. The readability part could be debatable though.

Comment: Thanks for the affirmation :) @JamesKanze "twisted"....lol

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there can be be a small readability advantage if that `someFuncThatReturnsBool` functions name reads like it's just some value, not particularly a boolean. Thousands (perhaps most people) would call me an idiot for that.

Normally, boolean variables and functions would be named `is_whatever` or `has_whatever`. So normally, an `if` statement reads as `if (is_whatever)` or `if (has_whatever)`. If I don't see that, or of course a relative operator, it seems a bit smelly to me.

But sometimes boolean variables and functions don't use that name formula, especially if the boolean type is specified via a template parameter. In that case, I might well use `if (whatever == true)`. Or, using Yoda conditions, that's `if (true == whatever)`.

Possible example...

```
std::map<int,bool> items;

...

if (items.at (key) == true)
{
  ...
}
```

Neither `at` nor `items` expresses that the value is boolean. `if (item)` doesn't read right - if anything, it suggests "if this is an item" which isn't the intent here. `if (item == true)` doesn't have this smell.

A smell is a distraction every time you revisit that code even if the smelly code is correct, so a couple of extra tokens is IMO worthwhile to clear that smell.

This is a reason why I'd generally prefer to name something `is_whatever` rather than `whatever_flag`. While `whatever_flag` is clearly intended to be a boolean, it still doesn't read quite right. It's the "grammar" of abbreviated English - "if flag" suggests "if this is a flag" rather than "if this flag is set".

Obviously, some newbies write `if (whatever == true)` because they have this mental template where every `if` needs a relative operator. This template is wrong, so this is one of those idiot-newbie stereotypes. There are some other similar cases, mostly obvious, like writing `value + 0`, `value * 1` or `value && true`. A slightly surprising one from Haskell...

```
main = do putStrLn "Hello World"
```

In this, the "mental template" is that any sequence of monadic actions requires a `do`. In this case, though, there's only one monadic action so there's no need to compose a sequence of actions into a single action. All that's needed is...

```
main = putStrLn "Hello World"
```

In this case, I'll reserve judgement on whether it's occasionally worth keeping the `do` for readability - I don't have the experience.

Anyway, personally, I think that having ridiculed people for doing something, it's hard to accept that sometimes there's a valid case for doing it. After all, the mental template is that `if (whatever == true)` is automatically ridiculous.

Certainly if you want a quiet life, it's best to never do that.

Comment: A worthy read... I like the map example, definatley helps to make it obvious in that case :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage to doing it that way. It could make it slightly more readable if it's not obvious from the function name that it should return a boolean, but in that case you'd be better off renaming the function

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage and the compiler will probably throw the "true =="-part away. If the function name makes clear that it returns a boolean (e.g. starting with "is" or "has"), then you can immediately see that it returns a boolean.

Maybe the code used to return error-codes as return values and this was refactored to a boolean, but the return-value check was not removed?

Comment: In which case, it wouldn't be `true == ...`, but `someValue == ...`.  (Of course, the idea of putting the constant on the left side of the `==` is rather twisted to begin with.)

Comment: Thanks for that :)  ... no, in this case the code was always meant to be boolean (or was edited so that it was obviously meant to be)

Comment: @JamesKanze Some people advocate constant on the left in order to protect against the dreaded "assignment instead of comparison" typo (i.e. to prevent `if (3 = a) ...` from compiling.) Not that it makes sense in this context.

Comment: @Rafał Dowgird - that's called "Yoda conditions". The kind of error it's there to prevent (`if (a = 3)` rather than `if (a == 3)`) should trigger a warning in modern compilers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference except the code with explicit comparison is longer and more difficult to read.